# how to calculate variance and std without import

Tags: python, python-3.x, variance

I have to calculate the mean,variance and the std in python.

Here is my code:

```
def mean(first_data_values):

    return sum(first_data_values) / len(first_data_values)

def variance(values):

    meanval = mean(values)
    return sum((values[i]-meanval) ** 2 for i in values)/len(values)

def std(values):

    return (variance(values)) ** (1/2)
```

So i get the wrong result. Any idea what`s wrong??

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't use the `statistics` module?

Comment: Probably should be `sum((i - meanval) ** 2 for i in values)/len(values)`

Comment: it`s not allowed for this homework

Comment: I would add an optional argument `mean` in the signature of `variance()` and `std()`. It lets you save time if you calculated the mean beforehand. The official python module does that.

Answer (score 2):

The error lies in the following line:

```
return sum((values[i]-meanval) ** 2 for i in values)/len(values)
```

`i` takes the value of every element in `values` one by one. You are then using it as an index in `values[i]`, but it should be just `i`.

Hence:

```
return sum((i-meanval) ** 2 for i in values)/len(values)
```

or

```
return mean([(i-meanval) ** 2 for i in values])
```

Comment: Or just `return mean([(i-meanval) ** 2 for i in values])`

Comment: Yep, even better!